# Copy to another column based on keyword in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
        Tel             |       Handy 
 _______________________|_____________________________  
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: +41 31 761 14 33
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 079 658 71 71
    Sprache: Deutsch     Handy: 076 517 20 94
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 079 296 00 65
    Tel.: 061 981 3804   Handy: 079 415 83 57
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 041 497 37 94
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 079 735 43 71
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 041 390 07 06
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 079 703 36 26
    Handy: 078 738 7222  franziskafroschmayer@me.com
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 044 776 88 60
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 044 740 82 19
    Sprache: Deutsch     Tel.: 076 335 77 51
    Tel.: 062 721 0677   aegerter_b@bluewin.ch
    Sprache: Deutsch     Handy: 079 483 17 65
```

I have the above two columns in a excel sheet. I would like to copy the all the Column values(not entire row) which has word "Handy" in **Tel** column and paste it in a column **handy**

I have no clue how to do that. Either in MS excel or google spreadsheet. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter the data in the "tel" column using the Text Filters -> "contains" option; then copy all elements that are still visible in "Tel" and copy them to "Handy". In the process you will overwrite whatever was in "handy" - but your question didn't suggest that that was a problem.

Suggest that you do this on a copy of the spreadsheet, not the original... just to make sure you don't mess it up. But this should work.